# OSGI and @Reference(unbind="-")

Tags: binding, osgi

I'm using OSGI Enroute, and one of the example programs I am looking at has the following:

```
@Reference(unbind = "-", name = "provider")
JDBCConnectionProvider jdbcConnectionProvider;
```

I don't see the "-" notation documented anywhere, can someone clear up what this means?

Comment: Copy paste error when moving from bind methods to field injection ... fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Declarative Services Specification:

> To declare no unbind method when the component type contains a method with the candidate name, the value "-" must be used.

This only applies to annotated methods (not fields as you show here) so it is most likely a mistake in the enRoute example you are looking at.

Comment: See https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/annotations/Reference.html#unbind() for the javadoc.